# Wanting to uninstall

Tags: samsung-galaxy-s-3

I have a game chef town. I have it on my phone and tablet. I was going to put the game on phone but I tapped new game. So now I cant get the game to be in the same place as the one on tablet. My question is can I erase the memory of this so it will take me back to where the game will say we found old?

Answer (score 0):

This could be solved by going to Settings>Application Manager>The App>Clear data. This is not a 100% guaranteed fix as the synchronization intervals for the server are unknown and it might not be able to synch back at all. Try this first and let me know what the effect is.

Comment: I have tried it. It just keeps making me either start new game or get old game back. If I wouldn't have push start new button that would have worked. I was trying figure how I could erase all of it data files anything so I could get the same one back. I just don't know what I need to erase to get it. Is there anything besides data that it keeps to get info from? Thanks for helping

Answer (score 0):

You could use this app called [Helium](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.koushikdutta.backup) to store the data from your tablet and restore it on your phone. I've used the app to restore game data on my phone after a factory reset, and some internet posts, [like this one](https://www.maketecheasier.com/move-game-progress-between-android-devices/), suggest that it is possible to do so in between different devices. It's worth a shot =)